# Using timer vs Task parallel library

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

I am writing a windows service and using Timer to invoke a method every minute. 
I have a below code

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Set up a timer to trigger every minute.
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

    _timer.Start();

}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{           
    StartProcessingWorkFlow();
}
```

However I want to replace timer with Task Parallel Library?
I read upon `Task.Delay()` but it seems to work only 1 time.
I want code to get invoked every 1 minute until its is stopped.

Comment: Sounds like the `Timer` is exactly what you need. You still can start a `Task` in the `Elapsed` event, but the `Timer` functionality seems very well suited to your needs... Is there any reason you want to remove the timer?

Comment: Nice snippet, it documents your problem quite well :(

Comment: StartProcessingWorkFlow(); is a very resource intensive method. So I want to take adavantage of TPL to use multiple cores. I was wondering if TPL has anything similar to TIMER.   Besides I can pass a cancellation token and stop processing if required.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with Task inside a loop:

```
while(true){
    await Task.Delay(60000);
    StartProcessingWorkFlow();
}
```

But I dont think this is the best way to do this. Try looking for [Rx.net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610)